# Committing offsets for multiple batches at once

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a kafkalistener which listens to a batch of messages at once looks like below

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topicName", container = "conatainer_name")
public void listenEvents(@payload List<ConsumerRecord<String,String>> records, Acknowledgement ack) {
    process(records);
    ack.acknowledge();//committing offsets
}
```

My question ,is there a way  to listen multiple batches of messages and commit only once .For example if I have 1000 messages in kafka topic I want to listen 100 messages at a time in the form of 10 batches and commit the offsets after processing 10 batches of messages.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no mechanism to aggregate multiple `Acknowledgment`s.

You can save off the `Acknowledgment` instances and ack them all individually when you are ready (be sure to do them in the right order).